# Gitlab Runner 403 forbidden error on Nuget Push

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I am trying to prepare a CI pipeline that ll pack and push the .dll to My custom nuget server on every commit.

.gitlab-ci.yml:

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:latest

stages:
  - build
  - pack
  - push
variables:
  project: "GitlabCITest"

before_script:
  - "dotnet restore"
  - "ls -al /builds/test/gitlabcitest/GitlabCITest/nuget.exe"

build:
  stage: build
  variables:
    build_path: "./"
  script:
    - "dotnet build"

pack:
  stage: pack
  script:

    - "cd GitlabCITest"
    - "mkdir tesdosyası"
    - "dotnet pack GitlabCITest.csproj"
    - "ls -al /builds/test/gitlabcitest/GitlabCITest/bin/Debug"
    - "dotnet nuget push --force-english-output /builds/test/gitlabcitest/GitlabCITest/bin/Debug/*.nupkg -s MyCustomNugetServerAddress -k MyApiKey"
```

When it runs i am getting 403 forbidden error on push jobs.

The error log:

```
$ ls -al /builds/test/gitlabcitest/GitlabCITest/bin/Debug
total 32
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Oct 11 06:57 .
drwxr-xr-x. 3 root root 4096 Oct 11 06:57 ..
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 3929 Oct 11 06:57 GitlabCITest.1.0.0.nupkg
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 4096 Oct 11 06:57 netcoreapp2.1
$ dotnet nuget push --force-english-output /builds/test/gitlabcitest/GitlabCITest/bin/Debug/*.nupkg -s MyCustomNugetServerAddress -k MyApiKey
info : Pushing GitlabCITest.1.0.0.nupkg to 'MyCustomNugetServerAddress'...
info :   PUT MyCustomNugetServerAddress
info :   Forbidden MyCustomNugetServerAddress 651ms
error: Response status code does not indicate success: 403 (Forbidden).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was all about password characters, i have a ';' in my apikey so it made a complication. just add ' character beginning and the end of your apikey if you have special characters in your apikey. 'apikey'